# Want to find out if iPhone can receive incoming calls (airplane mode)

Tags: iphone, core-foundation, airplane-mode

My application's users don't like interruptions like incoming phone calls. I want to find out if the device is in Airplane mode, warn the user about possible interruptions and recommend invoking Airplane mode.

The reachability examples tell me if the device has a network connection, but it's possible that WiFi is on while the phone is in Airplane mode.

Comment: Shouldn't the users be smart enough to turn on Airplane mode if they don't like being interrupted. I know you want to help the user by providing a helpful prompt to them, but really this seems more like a "user not knowing how to use their device" issue. That said, I don't think there is any Apple allowed API that can give you this information, directly or indirectly.

Comment: Things literally start falling out of the sky if users forget to turn on airplane mode: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MthsWKBdlU

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to check the **kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN** flag (have a look at the Reachability.m class and change it to your heart's content).

Comment: I am familiar with Reachability.m. kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN flag doesn't tell me what I want to know. Its purpose is to tell me if a network connection is going over cellular, not if cellular is available. If both cellular and WiFi are available, this flag is false.